# From seq to _* in Scala

Tags: scala, variadic-functions

Does anyone knows how we can convert from any Seq to _* in an automatic way? It's quite cumbersome to force the type every time we have a Seq and a method uses a parameter of type vararg.

```
def mean[T: Numeric](elems: T*): Double
...
elems = Seq(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
mean(elems) // this doesn't compiles
mean(elems: _*) // this compiles but it is cumbersome
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the only way. It's a reason why varargs are arguably best only used at the public interface of a library, and even then, particularly when you think the caller will be calling with literally specified elements instead of a collection. If a method will likely be called on a collection argument, varargs can backfire in its goal of reducing syntactic nois, as you've noticed.

Comment: Such a shame. Yes, I've noticed it. I'm going to refactor and change T* to Seq[T]. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If the method isn't generic, you can add an overload:

```
def mean(elems: Seq[Double]): Double = ...
def mean(elems: Double*)(implicit d: DummyImplicit): Double = mean(elems)
```

Alas, it doesn't work in this case:

```
scala> object X { def f[T: Numeric](x: T*) = x; def f[T: Numeric](x: Seq[T])(implicit d: DummyImplicit) = x }
defined module X

scala> X.f(Seq(1, 2))
<console>:9: error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition, both method f in object X of type [T](x: Seq[T])(implicit evidence$2: Numeric[T], implicit d: DummyImplicit)Seq[T] and  method f in object X of type [T](x: T*)(implicit evidence$1: Numeric[T])Seq[T] match argument types (Seq[Int])
              X.f(Seq(1, 2))
                ^
```

because the compiler thinks `T` could be `Int` or `Seq[Int]`, and stops before checking whether implicits are available for both (at least in Scala 2.10).

Comment: It's interesting your use of DummyImplicit here, thanks for the trick, I didn't know it.